# Cassandra - SSTable Readpth & Write Path

Tags: cassandra, datastax

**Hello Cassandra specialists!!!**

**How will go about analyzing Read path and Write path for Cassandra?**
Basically, I would like to know what is read path and write path measurements and if i give some sample row keys , how will I know, how many SStables are there currently for that particular Row Key and where is that located about details? Based on this detail I would like know what is causing slowness and for read path and what can be improved.
I am particularly interested in knowing **How many SSTables are there for particular RowKey and where they are located?** This is one of the POC that I am working on for the client.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Another possible mechanism could be to use 
`nodetool getsstables <keyspace><cf><key`
which will give you the list of sstables which contain the key.

Another option is to write a script which sort of runs/repeats the sstable2json on all the files in the folder and greps for the specific key. Once the key is found, you can write that file into some sort of datastructure and then later obtain the details of the same from the datastructure.

Comment: Yes That comamnd worked in windows as single node.When I ran that in linux and 3 node cluster..
./nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <cf> 'c11b3e8b-6f80-4900-abdd-93d9472b59df'
I got output as 
130.5.127.43
130.8.119.87

and I logged into one of the above machine and ran 
./nodetool getsstables <keyspace> <cf> 'c11b3e8b-6f80-4900-abdd-93d9472b59df'
but it brings no result.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Docs tend to be a good starting point:

- [Write path to compaction](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html)
- [About the read path](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_read_path_c.html)

> how will I know, how many SStables are there currently for that particular Row Key

You can use `sstable2json` to view the raw information contained within sstables in a json format and hunt down particular keys to see how they are distributed across replicas. This will be fiddly especially if you have a lot of sstables, so you can use `nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <table> <key>` to workout which node actually owns the key and then start converting sstables to json.

Comment: Hello Lyuben Todorov, Thanks for answering.I Understand how to find out which node owns data for particular key.Is there single command that I can use to find out how many sstables data is spread across for particular key? Are yousaying I ahve to convery every *Data.db sstables and findout how many files has data for that particular key? I am sure there must be single command to find out file names which has data for partcular key.Thanks,